# Add milliseconds to existing Unix time

Tags: bash, time

I have a script that returns Unix time in seconds, for example, 1374521719. I'd like to take in this time and place milliseconds to that. [Other posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-using-bash) show a simple example of this with the current time:

```
echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
```

When my script takes in the input of the Unix time, how do I to add the current milliseconds to that (if that even makes sense)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the Unix timestamp that you have (in seconds) to milliseconds, then add your milliseconds to it.

To convert the seconds to milliseconds, simply multiply by 1000 (or append "000", whichever is more convenient).

To add your own milliseconds count, you can just use bash's support for arithmetic expressions. To get the current number of milliseconds past the second, you can use date's `+%N` format specifier, which outputs nanoseconds past the second, and divide by 10^6 to get milliseconds.

Putting this together, if you already have a script or function `get_seconds` which outputs the number of seconds since the epoch, we get:

```
echo $(( ($(get_seconds) * 1000) + ($(date +%N) / 1000000) ))

     ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |    |                         |_ convert ns past sec to ms
     |    |
     |    |_ convert seconds to ms
     |
     |_ bash arithmetric expression
```

Note that this combines two completely separate timestamps, so while you get an increased number of digits (precision), you don't get any increased accuracy in the reported time. In fact, if (say) something happens just at the turn of the second, the first part may relate to second X and the second part may relate to second X+1, which can cause the resulting value to be off by almost one second. (You should have got X.998 and instead got X.002 because of the second boundary.)

Frankly, I fail to see how this could ever be more useful than, say, just appending "500" to the seconds to get the milliseconds at half the second (you will still be off by some amount, but you reduce the maximum error by roughly half).